# Ruby gems install error openssl with package installed

Tags: software-installation, ruby

I downloaded the ruby source and ran the usual

```
.configure
make
sudo make install
```

and it installed fine and `ruby -v` yields the expected `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]`

However when I want to run `gem install bundle` I get this error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
        cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

I have the `zlib1g zlib1g-dev` packages installed on my system (latest ubuntu LTS).

EDIT: running a `make clean` and `sudo make uninstall` and running through the process again solved this issue but now I get a new error.

`Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources`

Needless to say, openssl is installed (and always has been) as `which openssl` shows `/usr/bin/openssl`.

I tried running `gem update --system --source http://rubygems.org/` but even there still get the same error for openssl.

Comment: Why don't you used any package manager to install Ruby?

Comment: using apt to install ruby gives you a horribly outdated version and for security reasons we cannot use 3rd party managers like RVM to install ruby, it has to be from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `libssl-dev` package to be installed for building ruby with openssl support

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: logically I was looking for a package like `openssl-dev`. I installed the suggested package and am recompiling. I'll update here when that is done